# flutter project cant run in visual studio

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
> platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept licences before building app in visual studio.
This is only one time configuration to be done. Have you done it?

If not then run following command:

In Windows

```
%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

In Linux

```
yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

In macOS

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
yes | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

If still problem persist then let me know.